# Bash Search same domain in file

Tags: regex, bash, expression

I Want to print a line that contains the same domain.

For Example:

I have a file that contains string with "To:*some character*@yahoo.it" I want all the line with the same domain.
Is not really simple because the line can contain "From:*some character*@yahoo.it" with "To:*some character*@virgilio.it".

Comment: Show your sample input/output

Answer (score 0):

Is this simple `grep` command what you are looking for?

```
grep '@yahoo.it' yourfile.txt
```

Comment: No because if i use "grep '@yahoo.it' yourfile.txt" i take also the line that contains "From: *some character*@yahoo.it" and isn't what i want. I want the line that contains only "To: *some character*@yahoo.it"

Answer (score 0):

Use this regular expression :

```
grep "[t | T]o *: *[a-zA-z0-9]@yahoo.it" some_file
```